# Same order of element in group...

Tags: abstract-algebra

If we have two elements $a$ and $b$ in a group such that $a^3 = e$ and $b^3 = e$ does this imply that $a=b$? I suspect so, but I think im missing something trivial here?

Comment: If $a \neq 1$ and $a^3 = 1$, then $a^3 = b^3 = 1$ for $b = a^{-1}$, but $a \neq b$.

Answer (score 2):

No: Another counterexample:

Take $(1, 2, 3),\;(1, 3, 2) \in S_3$. Each of these permutations is of order $3$ (confirm that, if you need to), yet clearly $(1, 2, 3) \neq (1, 3, 2)$.

Comment: May I ask, if we have $a^3 \in G$ can we draw the conclusion that $a \in G$?

Comment: Not necessarily. However, if we know $a\in G$, then it's true that $a^3 \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

No not necessarily. Take the group $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ modulo $7$. Then $1^3 \equiv 4^3 \equiv 2^3$.

Answer (score 0):

A group element and its inverse always have the same order. If $a^3=b^3=e\implies a=b$ were true, we would be forced to conclude that every element of order $3$ equals its own inverse, that is, that every element of order $3$ actually has order (at most) $2$. Contradiction.

Answer (score -1):

No. Consider the group of integers mod 3.

Comment: $0^3=0, 1^3=1, 2^3=2$?

Comment: @HSN I think the poster meant the *additive* group of integers, mod 3, so $0^3 \to 0+0+0 = 0$, $1^3 \to 1+1+1 = 0 \mod 3$, $2^3 \to 2+2+2 = 0\mod 3$. So this indeed works.

Comment: Ah, of course. I was just confused by the answer given directly above it. My mistake.